# Modal popup shows its transition on f5

Tags: html, css, popup, target

I'm creating modal popup using `:target` without JavaScript. Everything was great until I started with a transition to make nice fade in/out. The modal is visible for transition time when page is refreshed.

```html
<a class = 'row__th__import' href="#popupTargets">Import</a>
...
<div class="popup" id="popupTargets">
   // some stuff
</div>
```

SCSS:

```css
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 100vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    margin: 3% auto;
    padding: 1%;
    background: $white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 500ms;
    &:target {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

It looks like visibility hidden doesn't affect this element immediately when page is loading

Comment: :target will require the DOM to be finished loading before it can happen, I would have thought. It would work as expected once the page is loaded, though. Also check your transition, I'm used to seeing it with time/transition type/one, some, or all elements.

Comment: Nathaniel Flick I changed to transition:  opacity 500ms, transform 500ms since i also want to affect scale() and now everything is as it should. I wonder why transition: all 500ms doesn't work correctly

Comment: I found out it is because all affects visibility and this causing the issue, but i need to transition this property later to make fade out. Is there a way to skip this first transition of visibility on page load?

Comment: Transition the opacity transition: .3s ease-in-out opacity; then on document load (jQuery or JavaScript) apply a class that reverses that opacity/visibility and transition: .3s ease-in-out all.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Thank you, it helped, but i just realized my whole css is loading with about .1s delay, maybe that was causing the issue... It's really strange cause i m building html with webpack from scss, so its directly in index.html in minified version.

Comment: If someone is also strugling with this, here is the solution https://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/
Loading js before body also works, but its really problematic idea